# Do I need to release Bitmap resources?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-studio, resources

I made a 2D game in Android studio that uses the Bitmap class to handle .png resources.  I've heard about the Bitmap.recycle() method to release resources but is this necessary?  If so, should this be done in the surfaceDestroyed() method?  Also, what would be the consequences of not releasing these resources?

Answer (score 0):

The answer differs based on the version of Android.  But in general, at least for modern versions-  calling recycle is a good idea when you're done with the bitmap to speed up release of the associated memory.  Its not an absolute necessity.  But not doing so when you're done with them may cause you to go into blocking GC if you run too low on memory, which can be a bad experience.